# Details of the Firefox add-on installation procedure

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am curious about the inner workings of the Firefox add-on installation procedure. I have noticed that the following steps take place when user installs an add-on from addons.mozilla.org:

1. The add-on is downloaded (probably in a temporary folder).
2. An installation confirmation dialogue box pops up ("install add-ons from authors you trust").
3. Upon clicking install, the add-on is stored in the /extensions/staged folder. Along with the add-on, there is also a JSON file like this: addon_id.json.
4. Firefox prompts the user to restart the browser.
5. After restart, the contents from the /extensions/staged/ folder are moved to the /extensions/ folder.

What I would like to know is:

- Which code portion in the Firefox source code is responsible for step 5? I am assuming some c++ or js code or some xpcom module is responsible for figuring out that an add-on is waiting to be installed in the staged/ folder, and performs the necessary steps (moving the files, registering the add-on etc.). Can anyone please point me to that module/code?
- Where is the add-on stored temporarily, when it is downloaded (step 1)?

Basically, I would like to alter some files after an add-on is downloaded at step 1, but before it becomes part of the browser (step 5). I want to add this functionality in the Firefox source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You analysis is mostly correct, it merely leaves out bootstrapped extensions. Bootstrapped extensions don't require a browser restart, they will be moved out of the `staged` directory and activated immediately.

The Add-on Manager is all JavaScript starting with Firefox 4. The important files are [amWebInstallListener.js](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/3a7b9e61c263/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/amWebInstallListener.js) (the component handling add-on installations from the web), [AddonManager.jsm](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/3a7b9e61c263/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/AddonManager.jsm) (the generic add-on management API) and [XPIProvider.jsm](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/3a7b9e61c263/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/XPIProvider.jsm) (the provider for XPI-packaged extensions).

1. `extWebInstallListener.onWebInstallRequested()` gets called with a bunch of `AddonInstall` instances (defined in `XPIInstall.jsm`) and creates an `Installer` instance that calls `AddonInstall.install()` for each of the installs. The downloads go into a temp file determined by `getTemporaryFile()` in `XPIProvider.jsm` (`tmp-foo.xpi` in the OS-specific temp directory).
2. `Installer.checkAllDownloaded()` determines that all downloads finished and displays a modal confirmation dialog (`URI_XPINSTALL_DIALOG`).
3. `AddonInstall.startInstall()` moves the add-on into the staging directory. Bootstrapped add-ons will be immediately installed after that. For other add-ons it continues to step 4.
4. `onInstallEnded` listeners are triggered - one of them shows the message that the browser needs to be restarted.
5. After a browser restart `XPIProvider.startup()` calls `XPIProvider.checkForChanges()` calls `XPIProvider.processPendingFileChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will keep me busy for a while!